# How to make windows system menu appear in MTPuTTY with alt-space

Tags: windows, putty

In MTPuTTY (Multi-Tab PuTTY) how can I get the system menu that appears for other applications with alt-space? So that I can Move, Minimize, Size, etc. the window?

[image: windows system menu]

It seems like sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't, depending on focus.

Comment: I myself switched to [MobaXTerm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) after being fed up with all of the PuTTY variants.  You should try it.  It has a built in drag and drop ftp like client that works "magically" without setting up ftp on the host and also has a built in X server to host X11 forwarding.  I am not connected to this company in any way other than I love this product.  Oh.. and I use it to do exactly what you are doing against multiple sessions/servers at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MTPuTTY session can focus on the terminal window, or on the application itself. The alt+space will work when focus is on the application.

Use crtl-` to change focus between the terminal window and the application itself. Once focus is on the application, alt-space will work.

The hotkey ctrl-` is configurable in Tools --> Hotkeys

[image]

An alternative is that PuTTY itself also has a setting that can help: Windows --> Behavior --> System menu appears on ALT-Space

Answer (score 0):

Click/select the MPutty Windows Bar on top of the page then press "Ctrl M"
to toggle Menu 'on' and 'off'